# Fetching data from Access Database into bootstrap designed panel

Tags: database, twitter-bootstrap, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

OK, here's the thing.

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <br />
    <legend><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">*** VALUE ***</a></legend>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
        <h3>3rd September</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consequatur ducimus. Necessitatibus, eaque laborum laudantium.
            Adipisci, explicabo, asperiores!
        </p>
        <p>
            First 255 character are written and others are put into...  
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalpostexplore">View More</a>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p class="text-muted">
            #hash1 #hash2 #hash3 
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" role="button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the panel I'm using to display my feeds. (it's an experimental social networking site)
What i do want to do is,
How'd you connect the database into the website in such a way that i can fetch value with the **value** shown above?

I tried doing it and I'm still learning so I can't do much.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Also this whole template is to be repeated for as many times as new posts are made. How should I use the repeater funcion?

Comment: what programming language do you use ?

Comment: It's VB. 
Would using eval be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I got it.
Set a repeater over the panel you create. 
And then make a connection with the database in repeater properties.

Use <%#Eval("FIELD NAME")%> to apply text.

Check out this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in7-KEtyCpg

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the append method from the html class there is a good example here http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-from-database-in-HTML-table-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I'm using an access database.
The <h3> tag has to hold the field x from table y.
Similarly all other tags have some and some fields to display.

How should I connect the database to the page? ON THE MASTERPAGE OR ON THE CONTENT PAGE?
And what coding to use?

After the VB coding is done, what should I use between the <H3> </h3> tags to display my x field?

I'm sorry if this is extremely noobish but I have no idea.